# Split Keynote Builds Into Separate Slides

Tags: keynote

I need a method that takes a Keynote presentation with multiple build animations (appear, disappear, etc.) as input and splits each slide into several new slides, one new slide for each build animation. Essentially, I need the PowerPoint plugin [PPspliT](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~rimondin/downloads.php) equivalent for Keynote.

To illustrate the problem with an example, suppose I have [this Keynote](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i4M7rrJuUVOV9Ed2kyb1F1Q3M/edit?usp=sharing) as input:

[image: input]

Notice that there is one slide with three build animations.

I desire [this Keynote](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i4M7rrJuUVRUlrMTFWTW5aUUE/edit?usp=sharing) as output:

[image: output]

Notice that there are now four slides, with none of the slides having build animations. Both input.key and output.key produce the same slideshow.

Comment: What I do in this case is to copy the first slide two times and then delete manually from each the parts that should be contained elsewhere. The list in the build order window is very helpful for selecting the right elements.
But I do not know of a tool which does this for you.

Comment: You could always export to PP then re-open in Keynote.  But the @PeterKämpf comments is my approach too.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late, but I know how to do this.
Under the File Menu in Keynote, select "Export to", then choose "Images". 
In the following window, check the box that says "create an image for each stage of builds". Go to the folder where you saved those images, then drag them all back into a new keynote doc.

Comment: The same option is available when you export to PDF as well.